# Check whether page was created as Page or modal page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page (`UpgradePage`) where I need to load the same page using `push/setRoot` through `side menu` as well a `modal page`.

**Q:** On this method `upgradeLater()` where I need to decide whether it should go to another page `HomePage` or just `close` it as `popup` using `this.viewCtrl.dismiss();`. Can you tell me how to do that?

**Note:** In other words how to find out `page` was created as `modal` or not?

*upgrade.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-upgrade',
  templateUrl: 'upgrade.html',
})
export class UpgradePage {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  upgradeLater() {
    if("comming from side menu"){
     this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
   } else{
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); //if loadded this page as modal page
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could try `typeof page.dismiss === 'function'` to see if the page has a `dismiss` function? As I think that is specific to a modal.

Comment: I have tried this `if (typeof this.viewCtrl.dismiss === 'function') {` But it gives this error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` @SimonBrazell

Comment: a hacky way is to just send a boolean variable through navparams and check it

Comment: Yes, I did kind of that way. But try to find a better way here. It seems not. `const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('UpgradePage', { data: 'modal' });` @SurajRao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter to the page when you create it as modal or regular page.

for modal:

```
let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(UpgradePage, { type: 'modal'});
```

for regular page:

```
this.navCtrl.push(UpgradePage, {type: 'page'});
```

then in your `UpgradePage`:

```
type;
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams)
{
  this.type= navParams.get('type');
}

upgradeLater() {
  if(this.type=='page'){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
  } else{
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); //if loadded this page as modal page
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:
actually in `navCtrl` the modal and regular page are the same and if you use `push()` you can close them just with `pop()`.
more info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)